# how to the callout display number caller with Originate and asterisk?

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami, callout, asterisk-ari, asterisk-java

i have a question.
In asterik 11, i callout to a other phone by originate use command:

```
exten=>s,n,Originate(SIP/voiceNetwork/,exten,callout,s,1,30)
```

When the call to called, the call display is UNKNOWN, i want to it display number caller.
Please help me!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert into your callout extension something like:

```
exten => _X.,1,Set(CALLERID(name)=Name)
```

or

```
exten => _X.,1,Set(CALLERID(num)=12345678910)
```